# Getting an unexpected 'System.StackOverflowException' in C# code

Tags: c#

I have the following code and for some reason i am getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in WpfApplication1.exe`at the line :`this.JointName =
>   joint;`inside the`public Customer(String joint, String action)

when i run the code.

Class1.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public String JointName { get; set; }
        public String ActionName { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>();

        public Customer(String joint, String action)
        {
            this.JointName = joint;
            this.ActionName = action;
            this.lst.Add(new Customer(this.JointName, this.ActionName));
        }

        public List<Customer> GetList()
        {
            return this.lst;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Customer Data1 = new Customer("Joint1", "Action1");
            List<Customer> List = Data1.GetList();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = List;

        }
    }
}
```

Can you guys see what i am doing wrong here? i have no idea where i could have an infinite loop..

Comment: Basically, when you create a Customer, it adds to the internal list of customers a new Customer, which adds to its internal list a new Customer, and so on...

Comment: You are repeatedly initlaize the Cosntructor infinte times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public String JointName { get; set; }
        public String ActionName { get; set; }


        public Customer(String joint, String action)
        {
            this.JointName = joint;
            this.ActionName = action;

        }


    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs Code:

```
 namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Customer Data1 = new Customer("Joint1", "Action1");
                List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
                list.add(Data1);
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly calling the `Customer` constructor recursively. So your call stack looks like this:

```
Customer(String joint, String action)
Customer(String joint, String action)
Customer(String joint, String action)
Customer(String joint, String action)
Customer(String joint, String action)
...
```

With each method waiting to call `list.Add` after completion.

It just happens that the call to the `set` property of `JointName` is the final method call that breaks the stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for Customer contains a call to itself on the last line:

this.lst.Add(new Customer(this.JointName, this.ActionName))

That is the source of our error.

Comment: Expand your answer. Say why it causes an error etc. and what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Customer always performs "new Customer", which then calls the constructor of Customer, and so on, ad infinitum.